# Why is my TypeScript giving an error 'does not exist on type'?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying some very basic code that I converted from JavaScript:

```
export function getBroker(row) {
    return row[3];
}

export default getBroker;
```

I'm getting the following error message:

Property 'getBroker' does not exist on type '(row: any) => any'

Edit: In a separate file, I'm trying to use the library as follows:

```
import lib from './lib';
lib.getBroker(...);
```

How do I properly import my function?

Comment: The error is not caused by the code you posted. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: The default export is the function `getBroker`. You import it and try calling `getBroker` on this function. So, basically, you're trying to call `getBroker.getBroker(...)`(since `lib` refers to the `getBroker` function). To fix your code, call just `lib(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You export the function twice, so you have two choices for solving this.

1) Import the `export function getBroker`:

```
import { getBroker } from './lib';
```

2) Import the `export default getBroker`

```
import getBroker from './lib';
```